# Reload/Refresh 2 separate id in an Django HTML template using Ajax Javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, ajax

I have 2 different ids in a Django template.

The 1st is `id="start"` and the 2nd is `id="log_form"`. My current status is that when a button with the id of `#customSwitches` is clicked the `id="start"` is refresh and I want to add `id="log_form"` to this update as well. They are in separate locations in the HTML template.

I have commented my trials as they are not working.

Here is the ajax:

```
    $(document).ready(function(event){
        $(document).on('click','#customSwitches', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var status= $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'{% url 'app:bla' %}',
                data:{'active' : status, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':'{{csrf_token}}'},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(response){
                    $('#start').html(response['form']),
                    //I am trying to refresh #log_form also the same way same #start gets refreshed                       
                    //$('#log_form').html(response['form2']),
                    //What else should I add here to change the id of another part of the html called #log_form                    
                    console.log($('#start').html(response['form','div']));
                },
                error:function(rs, e){
                    console.log(rs.responseText);
                },
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is part of the views to explain what I am doing

```
def change_status(request, id):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('active') == 'true':
            # .......do stuff
            context = {
                'active': ''
            }
            html = render_to_string('app/button.html', context,request=request)
            #html2 = render_to_string('app/log_form.html', context,request=request)
            #return JsonResponse({'form': html}, {'form2': html2})
            return JsonResponse({'form': html})
        else:
            print("Fail")
    else:
        print("Fail")
```

Now when I click certain button `#start` only gets refreshed not the whole page.

***My question:*** How can I get `#log_form` also to get refreshed along with `#start` at the same time.

Here is my trials that added the HTML but without updating the Django template:

```
Trial 1

            $("#log_form").load(window.location.href + " #log_form", function() { console.log("loaded") });

Trial 2
onclick="test(event)"

<script>
    function test(event){
        document.getElementById("log_form").innerHTML = `{% include 'app/log_form.html' %}`
        event.preventDefault()
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the code of how are you triggering `$.ajax()` on clicking certain button `#start`. You need to add `event.preventDefault()` to avoid default action of button which might be the cause of complete page reload. In the same place you can trigger the action of `#log_form` whatever it is

Comment: I added the full script

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#log_form").load(location.href+" #log_form >*","");
```

Try this one, i used to use this in similar situations when i had to refresh a div only on ajax success.